# Is there a method if application was closed in multitasking?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Is there a method like: wasTerminated or something like that? I want to display the user an alertsheet, if he has completely closed the app from multitasking. At the moment I have implemented my code in the `DidEnterBackround`, but is there another way to fix this? That would be very useful for me.

Sorry I'm a newbie and I didn't find a solution on the net.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not 100% on this, but I'm pretty sure that killing an app from the mutli-task bar literally `kill`s the process, which means the only technical solution would be POSIX control signal handlers, which I don't think Apple allows us to register.

Comment: Apps can't perform tasks after they've been closed from multitasking unless they have special permissions to do minimal background execution (ex. The Mail App). And even at that, I think you're limited to non-UI functions (in other words a UIActionSheet probably won't fly). Maybe you'd be interested in something called Push Notifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Background applications can be terminated at any time, and there's no way for an app to tell whether it was terminated by the user (through the multitasking switcher) or by the system.

Your only notifications are –applicationDidEnterBackground:, –applicationWillEnterForeground:, and –application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:.  With these notifications you can tell if some background task completed or not, but you can't tell how your app was terminated.

Comment: well...okay but is there a way to let a local notification only pop up once? Thats was my actually problem and I thought that this could help me, but as you can see its not possble. Is there a way to display the notification the user gets only once? I could paste some code under my question if neccesary...Thanks

Comment: You mean UILocalNotification?  You should create a new question and ask about that specifically.

Comment: @NoahRaissi check out the Apple documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to show the message to the user, next time the user starts your app, or when the app is killed. If the app is killed by double clicking on the home button and killing it, and if you want to find out then, it is not possible.

But if the app is killed and the user starts the app again, then you will know whether the app is started fresh or did it become active.

The method

```
-(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application{
NSLog(@"Entering foreground");
```

}

will get called if it becomes active from background.

Other wise,

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
}
```

will get called where you can put your alert view.

You can easily experiment with these situations and figure out a way to do what you want.